# Import mesh as std::string using assimp

Tags: c++, stdstring, assimp

I am trying to load a mesh in assimp, which I don't provide as a file, rather an std::string read by using pointers provided by the linker, so that I can compile everything into one executable. I am basically searching for a fitting function returning aiScene*. But the only one I found in the manual is ReadFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by storing a file in an `std::string`, but there is a function called [`ReadFileFromMemory()`](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#a9b3c5e8b1042702f449e84a95b3324f6) that does exactly what you want.

If for some reason you don't like this option, you can always do a workaround and generate a temporary file from your string and then read it with `ReadFile()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the job